# rectifyStereoImages throwing "Not enough input arguments error"

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide, matlab-cvst

I am not trying to rectify a pair of stereo images but I am getting a strange error from the function

```
Error using rectifyStereoImages (line 106)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in RealTimeProcessing>captureButton_Callback (line 134)
[I1Rect, I2Rect] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2,stereoParams);
```

The line of code I have written is

```
[I1Rect, I2Rect] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2,stereoParams);
```

As you can see, the two images and the stereoParameters are present. I obtained the stereoParams by using the Stereo Camera Calibration Tool in MATLAB. Is there some input I am missing? The link to files are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xp56qybgntz2e7/files.zip?dl=0). I have included the two input images and the stereoParams.

Comment: It gives me a path to rectifyStereoImages.m files

/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/toolbox/vision/vision/rectifyStereoImages.m

Comment: It works when I use [this](http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/uncalibrated-stereo-image-rectification.html) tutorial. But I have calibrated my cameras so I am using [this](http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/rectifystereoimages.html) and it gives that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `class(stereoParams)` return?

`rectifyStereoImages` function has two syntaxes: calibrated and uncalibrated. For the calibrated case it takes the two images and a `stereoParameters` object. For the uncalibrated case it takes the two images and two projective transformation objects of class `projective2d`.

From what you've written it seems that your `stereoParams` is actually a projective transform object. In that case, `rectifyStereoImages` goes into the uncalibrated mode, and expects two of them.

Comment: I ran `class(stereoParams)` and realized the `stereoParams` object I had was stored as an 1x1 object with the original `stereoParams` inside it. So I just replaced the line `[I1Rect, I2Rect] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2,stereoParams);` with `[I1Rect, I2Rect] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2,stereoParams.stereoParams);` It works perfectly now. Thank You.